# How to make onclick event to div background image?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a div in html and assigned a background image to it, and i want to make an onclick event to that photo and don't know how, that's the div :

```
.add_btn {
background-color: #099;
position: absolute;
height: 35px;
width: 200px;
background-image: url(img/add.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
top: 265px;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give any information about your DOM except that you have an element with that class. It's hard to give a good answer but I'll try.

The following code will attach a function to the `onclick` events of all the elements with the `add_btn` class.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("add_btn").onclick =
    function () { 
        alert("Hello"); 
    };
```

Comment: sorry, but i put this code where?in the div itself or in the body inside a div tag ? or where ?

Comment: In your function that handles the `window.onload` event.

Answer (score 1):

Background image click is not possible. Because you have a foreground layer.
But you can use this JQuery for foreground image click...

```
$('.className > .Inner_Classname2= > img').click(function(e) {
alert("Ok");    
 });
```